# Question on sum of two Poisson independent variables, convolution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Consider the following exercise taken from Probability-1 by Shiryaev:

> Assuming that $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ are two independent Poisson random
>   variables with parameters, respectively, $\lambda_1 > 0$ and
>   $\lambda_2 > 0$, prove that $\xi_1 + \xi_2$ has Poisson distribution
>   with parameter $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$.

The exercise can be found on p. 294. Since the lecture I am attending (probability 1) is quite bad, I do self-teaching again. But I am a bit stuck on this exercise. I googled, but I think I need some more specific help understanding the concepts and not just the solution. The definition of a Poisson random variable is the following:

> Let $X$ be a random variable taking values $k = 0,1,2,\dots$ with
>   probabilities $p_k$. $X$ is a Poisson random variable if $$p_k =
>  e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \qquad k = 0,1,2,\dots$$

On p. 291 I found the following (the question is from this chapter):

> The distribution function of the sum of two independent random
>   variables is the convolution of their distribution functions.

So I am asking myself: **Is this useful here? How can I calculate the distribution function of the Poisson distribution?** I know I am lacking knowledge, but I think it is hard to learn this by myself. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why not just write it out?  The probability that the sum will have value $k$ is $\sum_{i=0}^k e^{-\lambda_1}\frac {\lambda_1^i}{i!}\times e^{-\lambda_2}\frac {\lambda_2^{k-i}}{(k-i)!}$.  Now just invoke the binomial theorem.

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot! Yes, I confused myself a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I see is to use *characteristic functions* (if not for that particular problem, for *many* others that will arise when studying convergence of random variables). For a real-valued random variable $X$, the characteristic function $\phi_X\colon\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{C}$ is defined by
$$
\phi_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]
$$
and [fully characterizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Properties) the distribution of $X$.

Now, given the [characteristic functions of a Poisson random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Examples), we can write, for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\begin{align}
\phi_{\xi_1+\xi_2}(t) &= \mathbb{E}[e^{it(\xi_1+\xi_2)}]
= \mathbb{E}[e^{it\xi_1}e^{it\xi_2}]
= \mathbb{E}[e^{it\xi_1}]\mathbb{E}[e^{it\xi_2}] \tag{Independence} \\
&= \phi_{\xi_1}(t)\phi_{\xi_2}(t) = e^{\lambda_1(e^{it}-1)}e^{\lambda_2(e^{it}-1)} \tag{Known expression}\\
&= e^{\lambda_1(e^{it}-1)+\lambda_2(e^{it}-1)}
= e^{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)(e^{it}-1)}
= e^{\lambda'(e^{it}-1)}
\end{align}$$
for $\lambda'\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \lambda_1+\lambda_2$. Since 
this last expression, $e^{\lambda'(e^{it}-1)}$, is the expression of the characteristic function of a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda'$, we can conclude that $\xi_1+\xi_2$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda'$.

---

**Additional:** if you want to prove that $t\mapsto e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)}$ is the expression of the characteristic function a Poisson distributed r.v. $X$ with parameter $\lambda$ (instead of saying "it is standard"), here is the derivation: for $t\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
\phi_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{itX}] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{itn} \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n}{n!}
= e^{-\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(e^{it} \lambda)^n}{n!}
= e^{-\lambda} e^{e^{it} \lambda}
= e^{\lambda(e^{it} -1)}
$$
using the fact that $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: How do we solve with moment generating function?@Clement C.

Comment: @Pole_Star Try to mimic the proof which uses the characteristic function. This should go through (the MGF and CF have very similar properties).